# Bash get exit code of a waiting process

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to get an exit code of a process i am waiting for and return it.
I have a script called script.sh that looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/PATH/TO/SCRIPT/another_script.sh"
$path
wait
cleanUpFunction
```

How can I return from script.sh the exit code of the another_script.sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't running `another_script.sh` in the background, so you don't need `wait` at all.

```
another_script.sh
exit_code=$?
```

If you *were*, though, the exit status of `wait` is the exit status of the background process.

```
another_script.sh &
# Do some other stuff
wait
exit_code=$?
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. The bash manual page for wait says: 
"If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero."
So I think in this example it will always be zero, even if `another_script.sh` returns a non-zero exit code.

Comment: If you have other background processes with the shell as a parent, sure.

Comment: In that case, though, you have two options: store the list of process IDs and wait on each one separately, or in newer versions of `bash`, use `wait -n` to wait for the  next job to complete. (With `-n`, though, you don't necessarily know *which* job's exit status you are getting.)